# Localization of a model category with respect to a class of maps

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I am little bit lost with the following (standard?) problem in model categories.

Suppose we have a Quillen adjunction between combinatorial model categories:

$$L:M\leftrightarrow N: R $$

and let $(M,Cof,Fib, WE)$ denote the model structure on $M$. I would like to know if it is possible to define a new model structure $(M, Cof, Fib^{'}, WE^{'})$ such that $f \in   WE^{'}$ if and only if $L(f)$ is a weak equivalence in $N$ ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very well-studied problem. Hirschhorn's book proves that, if $M$ is left proper and cellular then localization exists with respect to a set of maps. Jeff Smith figured out how to replace cellular by combinatorial; a nice write-up is in Barwick's paper [On Left and Right Model Categories and Left and Right Localizations](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.hha/1296223884). For a general class of maps, the existence of the localization is conjecturally equivalent to Vopenka's principle. See [The orthogonal subcategory problem in homotopy theory](http://www.ub.edu/topologia/casacuberta/articles/cacho.pdf) by Casacuberta and Chorny (and, also, [Definable orthogonality classes in accessible categories are small](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2792)).

However, if the class of maps is *accessible* then Lurie shows how to construct the localization, in Section 5.5 of Higher Topos Theory. Since you start with a left Quillen functor between combinatorial model categories, for you this means $L$ should be an accessible functor and the weak equivalences of $N$ should be of small generation (see Prop 5.5.4.16).

Comment: I had a look to the Prop 5.5.4.16, it is written in terms of infinite categories. Unfortunately, I'm not used to that language. But If I understand the statement there, then the model categorical interpretation seems to be different in the sense that he uses the derived functor of L and not L... But I'm not sure about my interpretation... :)

Comment: Most of the model categorical proof is formal, and Hirschhorn does a nice job breaking it down into a series of lemmas. Lurie's proof handles the really hard part (as does Smith's proof, and Hirschhorn's via cellularity, based on Bousfield's original argument). So, you can plug Lurie's proof into a model categorical setting just as easily. See Barwick's paper to understand this better.